# postal-mime library error "TypeError: PostalMime is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mime-message, web-extension

I'm trying to use the [postal-mime](https://github.com/postalsys/postal-mime) JS library in a Chrome browser extension using Manifest V3. My extension spawns a service worker and I'm trying to use this library there. To import it, I tried both

```
const { PostalMime } = require("postal-mime");
```

and

```
import { PostalMime } from "postal-mime";
```

while my code looks like this:

```
const parser = new PostalMime();
parser.parse(result).then((email) => console.log(email));
```

The variable `result` contains a standard email message as a string that I'd like to parse.
In both cases, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: PostalMime is not a constructor
    at sw.js:66:1
(anonymous) @ sw.js:66
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ sw.js:61
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help,

GTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the library [emailjs-mime-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs-mime-parser). While not a real solution to the asked question and despite having fewer functionalities than postal-mime, at least I'm able to import it out of the box without thinkering with Webpack's config.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a [ES module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) so to import it in general you need to use webpack or browserify i.e. a build system for your extension. Luckily, in this case you can find a prebuilt js file on [unpkg.com](https://unpkg.com/browse/postal-mime@1.0.13/dist/) which you should download manually into the directory of your extension.

```js
import './postal-mime.js'; // path and .js suffix are required for native import!
const PostalMime = postalMime.default;

const parser = new PostalMime();
parser.parse(result).then((email) => console.log(email));
```

Note that since postal-mime.js is not a native ES module we used a nameless import to let the library create its export in a global variable. To see the name of the variable (`postalMime`) look at the beginning of the file where you'll see `exports.postalMime=`. As for `default` it is an internal mechanism used by npm module implementation, which you can see in devtools console when you inspect `postalMime` object. Other libraries may use multiple named properties instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm already using Webpack, do I have to add something to my Webpack configuration to have this library working? I would prefer this way so it's easier to update to future versions instead of downloading the file.

Comment: Debug it in devtools and inspect the webpack's module object.

Comment: BTW that their own demo page uses `const PostalMime = postalMime.default;`

Comment: I tried with `const PostalMime = require("../../node_modules/postal-mime").postalMime.default` which reflects my directory tree, but it stil doesn't work, it says `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')`. 
About inspecting webpack's module object, which is the actual name of the object? I tried to log both `WebPack` and `module` but both appear to not exist.

Comment: That was if I try to define the constant inside my service worker. If I instead put `const PostalMime = require("postal-mime").postalMime.default;` in my WebPack config, it fails while compiling with the error `ReferenceError: self is not defined`.

Comment: Webpack module object is the thing evaluated by `require("...")` so you need to assign it to a separate variable, set a breakpoint in devtools, then inspect it.